# Can I install Polyiso over a popcorn drywalled ceiling?

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I have a mobile home with a vaulted ceiling and a thin drywall with popcorn finish.

I would like to install a fire rated polyiso foam board (Mansfield CI max or Dow Thermax) on the ceiling, then finish with light weight ceiling tiles.  The weight of any ceiling finish has to be light so as not to overload the mobile home roof trusses, so additional drywall for a fire rating is a not practical.

If this is a feasible plan, I need advise for what mechanical fasteners or adhesives to use.

Comment: Why not remove the old drywall, install the foam and put new drywall up instead of ceiling tiles?

Comment: Thanks Matt...I could... a ton more labor and more expense.  I hate doing Drywall especially on a ceiling.

Comment: I get it, it is never fun, but are you sure you're not going to overload the roof by adding more material? What exactly is your end goal?

Comment: Matt  I want to add insulation value and cover the popcorn ceiling.  The 4X8 insulation board only weighs 8.25 lbs and ceiling tiles would be polystyrene.  I have heard of others adding a masonite beadboard (31 lb per sheet), or even a layer of 3/8  (38lb per sheet)Drywall to cover a mobile home ceiling with good results.  I just want to add insulation value as well without, the extra weight.

Comment: You mention that your foam board is fire rated which is great, are the polystyrene tiles your looking at fire rated as well? I would be hesitant to use any non rated polystyrene products that would be exposed due to the potential for toxic fumes in the case of a fire.

Comment: They claim the tiles are fire rated for ceiling installations.   If  I stay light enough on the polyiso foam, I could use a different  non polystyrene product for finishing.  My other concern is  adequate adhesive or mechanical attachments for the foam board.  The trusses are made of 2X3 material and 30 years old.  I don't want to split and damage them with screws.  At a minimum I would want to predrill.  Am I crazy to think of just adhesive or a minimum of screws?  Adhesives say they will hold 24lbs in a 4X8 sheet , but that is on a good surface.  This is a popcorn ceiling finish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

It'll take some work to do things right. I wouldn't trust an adhesive alone to carry the load, especially with a popcorn ceiling finish.

I would use screws to affix your foam board panels ensuring that your attaching to the center of your trusses. Given the age of the material it may be worth while to drill pilot holes for your screws. As far as fasteners go I would look at a pan head, modified truss or a combination of either one paired with a fender washer. I would ask the manufacturer of the foam board what the recommended fastener pattern is for affixing the panels or refer to the install instructions if any were provided.

You should then be able to follow the manufacturers installation recommendations for the polystyrene ceiling tiles or come back here and ask a follow up question for further guidance.